# How do I access GigE camera features from TwinCAT code?

Tags: camera, twincat, gigevision

I would like to access (= read and write) GigE camera features, like exposure time, etc. from TwinCAT code (TwinCAT Vision) during runtime, instead of using the configuration assistant.

I am not able to find a solution in TwinCAT documentation. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it now.

Use "`FB_VN_WriteRegister_UDINT`" or equivalent

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf7xxx_tc3_vision/5366388491.html

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf7xxx_tc3_vision/13372868747.html